# How to construct double integral to find the area, given $\mathsf{D}= { \left( x,y \right): y \geq x^2-1 , y \leq 2x+2 , y \leq 3}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, iterated-integrals

I don't understand this topic honestly.

I thought there is supposed to be two types of ranges for x and y.
$$\therefore \space \mathsf{for} \space \space x^2-1 \leq 3 \space ; \space x \in [-2,2] \space \space \mathsf{and} \space \space y \in [x^2-1,3]$$
$$\therefore \space \mathsf{for} \space \space x^2-1 \leq 2x+2 \space; \space x \in [-1,3] \space \space \mathsf{and} \space \space y \in [x^2-1,2x+2]$$

Then I drew the graphs of both cases separately:
[image]
And constructed what I understood from this:
$$\displaystyle \int \limits^2_{-2} \int \limits^3_{(x^2-1)} (4-x^2) \mathsf{d}y \mathsf{d}x + \int \limits^3_{-1} \int \limits^{2x+2}_{x^2-1} (2x+3-x^2) \mathsf{d}y \mathsf{d}x$$
Apparently, from what I've seen, my way is not correct. What is the correct way and reason to find this double integral?

Comment: This is a 2D graph, you only have to find the area, not the volume or anything more than the area. You don't need a double integral for this.

Comment: If you are using double integral to find area, the integral is $\displaystyle \iint 1 \ dy \ dx$. You are subtracting bounds of $y$ and using that as integrand. In that case you cannot again integrate it wrt $dy$. Then it is simply single integral over $dx$.

Comment: Also your bounds of $x$ is incorrect. You should plot them together rather than two separate plots.

Answer (score 2):

Combining those two graphs, you can notice that the area is divided into two sections:

from -1 to $\frac{1}{2}$ that is lower constrained by $x^2-1$ and upper constrained by $2x+2$,
from $\frac{1}{2}$ to 2 that is lower constrained by $x^2-1$ and upper constrained by $3$.

Can you continue on your own from there?